# Insert to table from a temporary table

Tags: performance, sql, t-sql

I created a procedure involving dynamically collecting from various projects (databases) some records into a temporary table and from that temporary table I am inserting into a table. With a `WHERE` statement, unfortunately, when I checked with the execution plan, I found out that this query part takes a long time to load. How can I optimize this `INSERT` part or the `WHERE` statement?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.PROJECTS_TESTS ( PROJECTID, ANOTHERTID, DOMAINID, is_test)
    SELECT * FROM #temp_Test AS tC
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 
                        FROM dbo.PROJECTS_TESTS AS ps WITH (NOLOCK)
                        WHERE ps.PROJECTID = tC.projectId 
                        AND ps.ANOTHERTID = tC.anotherLink 
                        AND ps.DOMAINID = tC.DOMAINID 
                        AND ps.is_test = tC.test_project 
                        )
```

Comment: Database questions should include the schema of the table(s) you're using. Please add sufficient context to make this code reviewable.

Answer (score 1):

The `NOT EXISTS` is usually the recommended version, but you should remove the `TOP 1`, it's not needed. Hopefully the optimizer is smart enough to remove it automatically, but those four columns are probably unique anyway.

I would suggest trying MERGE instead:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.PROJECTS_TESTS AS ps
USING #temp_Test AS tC
  ON ps.PROJECTID = tC.projectId 
 AND ps.ANOTHERTID = tC.anotherLink 
 AND ps.DOMAINID = tC.DOMAINID 
 AND ps.is_test = tC.test_project 
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN INSERT ( PROJECTID, ANOTHERTID, DOMAINID, is_test)
     VALUES ( tC.PROJECTID, tC.ANOTHERTID, tC.DOMAINID, tC.test_project)
```

There's no `WHEN MATCHED` branch, thus equivalent to your Insert/Select.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely agree with the left join above, this should improve things a lot. How often does this run and how many records are typically in the aggregated data? Can this be run whilst another call to this procedure is in process?

If you're putting many records in to your variable you may end up with tenpdb contention, which fortunately is what everything uses. When I've had performance issues before I've simply sqlbulkcopy into real, but still temp as in usage, not definition. Then one `UPDATE` statement to update what I wanted to update, then truncate those insert tables. This gives you great insert performance, and decent update performance without destroying tempdb (and this your server performance overall, not just in this query)

Answer (score -1):

You should not use a *

```
INSERT INTO dbo.PROJECTS_TESTS (PROJECTID, ANOTHERTID, DOMAINID, is_test)
SELECT * 
FROM #temp_Test AS tC
left outer join 
dbo.PROJECTS_TESTS AS ps WITH (NOLOCK)
   on ps.PROJECTID  = tC.projectId 
  AND ps.ANOTHERTID = tC.anotherLink 
  AND ps.DOMAINID   = tC.DOMAINID 
  AND ps.is_test    = tC.test_project 
where ps.PROJECTID is null
```